# Android notification setAutoCancel() won't work when using setPrimaryClip() in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-notifications, clipboardmanager

I have encountered a strange behavior trying to make a very simple app. I'm firing a notification and when the user clicks on it I copy some random text to the clipboard. Here's how I fire the notification:

```
// Build notification
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("test", "hello");
PendingIntent broadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Hello!")
        .setContentText("Hi!")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentIntent(broadcastIntent)
        .setOngoing(false)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setTicker("Click me!")
        .setAutoCancel(true);
notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());
```

And this is my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class NotificationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public NotificationBroadcastReceiver() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent 
        // Copy the text to the clipboard when notification is clicked
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
}
```

I'm just copying an empty string to the clipboard. On this way, when I click on the notification it doesn't goes off as it should when setting `setAutoCancel(true)`, **BUT** if I remove the line:

```
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

From the `BroadcastReceiver` then the notification is dismissed on click as it should. Why is this happening?

Comment: When you click on the notification, is there anything in the unfiltered log? How are you registering the receiver?

Comment: This is how I register the receiver in my manifest: `<service android:name=".CBWatcherService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" />`

Comment: What about in the unfiltered log when you click on the notification?

Comment: No errors or warnings AFAIK